# How to mock a MutinyEmitter in Quarkus?

Tags: java, mockito, quarkus, mutiny

I'm trying to unit test a class that uses `MutinyEmitter` to send messages. It looks like this:

```java
public class PaymentReversalService {
  @Inject
  @Channel("payment-reversal-out")
  MutinyEmitter<Payment> emitter;

  public Uni<Payment> reverse(String paymentId) {
    // Imagine that createPaymentReversal() is a private method that does all the hard work
    Payment payment = createPaymentReversal(paymentId);
    return emitter.send(payment);
  }
}
```

In my test, I want to use Mockito to mock the emitter and check if the message is being sent correctly. So far, I have been mocking my dependencies using the `@InjectMock` annotation. But it doesn't seem to work with `MutinyEmitter`.

I try to inject the mock like this:

```java
@InjectMock
@Channel("payment-reversal-out")
MutinyEmitter<Payment> emitter;
```

But then I get this exception:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestInstantiationException: Failed to create test instance
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.InjectMock - the injected bean does not declare a CDI normal scope but: javax.enterprise.context.Dependent. Offending field is emitter of test class class br.com.bank.regag.bar-payment.reversal.service.PaymentReversalServiceTest
```

How can I fix this? Or which other path can I take to test this class?

Comment: You cannot inject a channel as a MutinyEmitter (it's not the same type of emitter). Also, I would recommend using the in-memory trick to test your emitter: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/4.4.0/concepts/testing/